# How can I define the location of NLog file in code?

Tags: logging, configuration, nlog

Is there a way to define what config file NLog is supposed to use directly using c# code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this (note that I have neither compiled nor tested this):

```
string path = GetThePathToYourNLogConfigFile();
LogManager.Configuration = new XmlLoggingConfiguration(path);
```